# vuetify v-select custom item, how to close menu when item click

Tags: vuetify.js

```
<v-select :items="[1,2, 3 ]">
    <template v-slot:item="{item, props}">
        <div>
            {{ item  }}
        </div>
    </template>
</v-select>
```

After use v-select custom item slot, all event are not work anymore.
The menu always open even  when item clicked.

The select menu should close when item is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`props` in slot props contains an ´onClick`  handler, that selects the element and closes the menu. You need to bind it to your content:

```html
<v-select :items="[1,2, 3 ]">
    <template v-slot:item="{item, props}">
        <div v-bind="props">
            {{ item  }}
        </div>
    </template>
</v-select>
```

Comment: I'm grateful for your response. Could you please clarify how to find this information? I couldn't locate any details about it in the Vuetify documentation

Comment: Yes, the documentation is still quite sparse unfortunately. Particularly the API documentation could do more than give the type as `Record<string, unknown>`. In v2, `props` was separated in `attrs` and `on`, which made it more apparent and easier to recognize from other components that use the same mechanism, like VDialog. I think I know the structure from there. So to find the information, I guess you either have to recognize the structure, or piece it together from inspecting the props in the console or the sources. Not the best way, I agree